# Prolog getting dynamic fact values

Tags: prolog, prolog-directive-dynamic

While learning Prolog, I am writing a text-based game, this is some of it:

```
NewHealth is Health - Damage,
retract(stat(Target, health, Health)),
assert(stat(Target, health, NewHealth)),
```

I got an error about static procedures but a simple search fixed it, when running the game I would just quickly say `dynamic stat/3`. After that however, I get an error further up in the file where I declare the Health variable:

```
stat(Target, health, Health),
```

I narrowed down the problem to this (prolog console):

```
| ?- assert(test(a)).
yes
| ?- listing
test(a).
yes
| ?- dynamic test/1
yes
| ?- listing
yes
```

After being declared dynamic, it isn't in the static database anymore. But with a google search a couldn't find a case that has the same problem as mine. I just need to query and retract/assert a single database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dynamic](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=declare)/1 is a directive. Place it near to top of your file, with this syntax

```
:- dynamic stat/3.
```

Comment: How is that different to just typing it in?

Comment: a directive is resolved at compile time (say, when Prolog loads your file). Now it's unclear to me *when* you type in, but probably, you mean at *runtime*. It's data, then...